# How do I get the rows to columns to be the row and vice versa

Tags: python, math

## Here is some code I wrote

```
def binomial_coefficient(x,y):

    if y == x:
        div = 1
    elif y == 1:         
        div = x
    elif y > x:          
        div = 0
    else:                
        a = math.factorial(x)
        b = math.factorial(y)
        c = math.factorial(x-y)  
        div = a // (b * c)
    return(div)

def problem_9():
    for k in range(6):
        empty = '\t'
        for zed in range(1,6):
            X_sub = (10*zed,(1/5)*zed)
            n = X_sub[0]
            P = X_sub[1]
            formula = binomial_coefficient(n,k)*(P**k)*(1-P)**(n-k)
            empty = empty + str(formula) + '\t'
        print(empty)

problem_9()
```

I have the code giving me the correct mathematical values but I need the first column to switch places with the first row. I would like the same thing to happen for each subsequent iteration of the loops. Can anyone help?

Comment: You mean the *transpose*?

Comment: Yes, Transpose is the proper word.

Answer (score 0):

just permute the indices :

```
for zed in range(1,6):
    empty = '\t'
    for k in range(6):
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked fine.